# Typecasting DXVA2_Fixed32 to Float in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, directx, type-conversion

```
DXVA2_Fixed32 a = DXVA2_Fixed32OpaqueAlpha();

    float f = (float)a;
```

This is throwing a compilation error

> "error C2440: Cannot convert from "DXVA2_Fixed32 " to Float.

My purpose is to assign "a"'s value to "f".

Can anyone kindly let me know How to assign DXVA2_Fixed32  type variable "a" to "a float variable "f".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a typecast like that. The [`DXVA2_Fixed32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type is a struct containing two fields with fractional and integer parts of the number.

You need to call [`DXVA2FixedToFloat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to perform the conversion.

```
float f = DXVA2FixedToFloat(a);
```

If ever you need to go in the opposite direction you can use the predictably named [`DXVA2FloatToFixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Once Again incredibly fast & correct response. Thanks a lot David!!  Stackoverflow is simple superb. :)